# Weakly null sequences in projective tensor products

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, tensor-products, banach-algebras

First, I'd like to record a question that may still be open. The snippet below is taken from [DiestelPuglisi2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2008.03.001).
[image]

Second, let $E$ be a Banach space, $(u_n)$ be a weakly null sequence in the projective tensor product $\displaystyle E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*$, and $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence in $B(E^*) = (E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*)^*$ such that $x_n\to 0$ in SOT and $x_n^*\to 0$ in SOT ($x^*$ is the operator dual of $x\in B(E^*)$).

**Question 2.** Do we have $\langle u_n,x_n\rangle\to 0$ ?

It's known that the answer is yes if $E$ is a Hilbert space (e.g., [Lemma 5.5](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fpThBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA151) in Chapter 3 of Takesaki's vol. 1).

---

**edit (2023-02-12)** As it was pointed out by Matthew Daws in the comments below, Q2 is equivalent to asking whether $x_n\to 0$ uniformly on weakly compact subsets of $E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*$. This is indeed the convergence in the Mackey topology $\tau(B(E^*),E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*)$.

Mackey topology on a dual Banach space $X$ coincides with the locally convex topology generated by the seminorms of the form $x\to\|Tx\|$, where $T:X\to R$ is a weak$^*$ continuous operator into a *reflexive* Banach space $R$ [Proposition 2.1 in [Peralta2007](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-22-2/22P2Pera-congreso.pdf)].

On the other hand, Mackey topology on a Von Neumann algebra $M$ coincides with the strong$^*$ topology on bounded sets [Theorem 2.7 in [Akemann1967](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1967-0206732-8)].

In summary, Q2 could equivalently be phrased as:

**Question 2-2.** Are the two locally convex topologies below on $B(E^*)$ *sequentially* equivalent?

- given by the seminorms of the form $x\to\|Tx\|$, where $T:B(E^*)\to R$ is a weak$^*$ continuous operator into a *reflexive* Banach space $R$.
- given by the seminorms of the form $x\to\|x\xi\|$ and $x\to\|x^*\gamma\|$, for $\xi\in E$ and $\gamma\in E^*$. Needless to say the virtual analogy to the strong$^*$ topology.

Footnote: Yet, there's third topology that coincides with the strong$^*$ topology on the bounded subsets of $M$: the locally convex topology generated by the seminorms of the form $x\to\|Tx\|$, where $T:M\to H$ is a weak$^*$ continuous operator into a *Hilbert* space $H$.

---

**edit (2023-02-15)** The two topologies in Q2-2 above are sequentially equivalent for $E=\ell^p$, $1<p<\infty$.

Let $b(Y)$ denote the unit ball of $Y$, and $1/p+1/q=1$. For $l = (n_1,n_2,m_1,m_2)\in\mathbb{N}^4$, the sets
$$ W_{l}
 = m_1\sum_{k=1}^{n_1} b(\ell^p_{n_1})\otimes b(\ell^q)
 + m_2\sum_{k=1}^{n_2} b(\ell^p)\otimes b(\ell^q_{n_2})
$$
are relatively weakly compact subsets of $\ell^p\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^q$. Here $\ell^p_n$ should be interpreted as the fin. dim. subspace of $\ell^p$ spanned by the first $n$ standard basis elements.

For a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B(\ell^p)$, $x_n\to 0$ uniformly on each $W_l$ if and only if $x_n\to 0$ in SOT and $x_n^*\to 0$ in SOT.

Second, as shown in the proof of Theorem 1.1 in [Rodriguez2022](https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/haac036), for any weakly compact subset $K\subseteq\ell^p\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^q$, there exists $l\in\mathbb{N}^4$ such that $W_l$ almost absorbs $K$, i.e., $\forall\epsilon>0\hspace{2mm}\exists t>0$ such that $K\subseteq tW_l + \epsilon b(\ell^p\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^q)$. Having this in hand, it is fairly routine to check that $x_n\to 0$ uniformly on weakly compact sets if [$x_n\to 0$ in SOT and $x_n^*\to 0$ in SOT]. Thus, two topologies in Q2-2 are sequentially equivalent.

Comment: The dual of $(E \widehat\otimes_\pi E^*)$ is $B(E^*)$ not $B(E)$ (unless $E$ is reflexive).

Comment: @MatthewDaws I'm glad to see & thank you for your comment, especially when the dual Banach algebra $B(E)$ is keeping me awake at night these days. I sincerely value your insight & reply for both questions. Thank you also for pointing out the typos.

Comment: Takesaki's Lemma actually gives that $\lim_n \langle u_k, x_n \rangle = 0$ uniformly in $k$.  We know that for any fixed $u$, the conditions on $(x_n)$ mean that $\langle u, x_n \rangle \rightarrow 0$.  If Q2 is true for all sequences, it is true for all subsequences of some given sequences.  Then choosing subsequences appropriately shows that Q2 being true gives this uniform convergence.  I don't know if this is a useful observation or not.

Comment: @MatthewDaws In the same way, we can add two other equivalent conditions that $x_n\to 0$ uniformly on any weakly compact (resp. weakly precompact) subsets of $E\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}E^*$.